# open file from remote host with Kate

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, scp

Is it possible to open a file from a remote host with `Kate` like you can with vim:
 `vim scp://root@cc3//var/log/dp.log`?
 I've tried the following but neither option seems to work:
`kate scp://root@cc3//var/log/dp.log &` and `kate fish://root@cc3//var/log/dp.log &`

Comment: Try using `sftp://` (not sure about using it as command line argument, but it should work fine in "Open" dialogue). If it is still fails, you will need to install `kio_sftp` plugin (and `kio` itself)

Comment: @myaut that was it, using `sftp://` from the shell works fine. Move this comment into an answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, Kate interacts with user by dialogs, while you can also start editing a file in kate from command line with:

```
kate /file/to/open
```

Please do note that if you are not inside the kde/plasme desktop enviroment, kate may not be able to handle external files.

In this case, you can mount a remote filesystem with sshfs.

Example:

```
sshfs -p PORT_NUMBER USERNAME@SERVER:/path/to/remote/filesystem /mnt/remote_filesystem
```

Once done, you'll be able to:

```
kate /mnt/remote_filesystem/file_to_edit_with_kate
```

Following suggestion in comments, you can also install the kio-extra libraries, problably not available on your no-kde desktop

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kio-extras
```

Restarting your kate, you'll have your remote connections at hand inside the "+ Other locations" tab

[image]

Comment: When the `sshfs` connection to a server is unreliable, this is exactly the wrong answer. The desired behavior sought with the question would be similar to nearly all windows editors that handle remote editing and the connection is asynchronous and established with each `Ctrl+S`

Answer (score 6):

I know its old but I found solution best for me.

I use kubuntu so I have Dolphin and Kate.

In Dolphin I add Network => connection to my ssh

in Kate I installed plugin File system Browser.

Just open kate and paste path from dolphin in filesystem browser and safe like a project. So I have a tree of subdirectories of my project.

Something like this

```
sftp://youruser@youraddress.com:22/var/www/html/app/design/your-project-folder/
```

Comment: I do the same in Gnome shell with Nautilus and Geany, LOL